# How to get rid of old Localizable.strings?

Tags: iphone, localization, localizable.strings

So I have this app that is already on the app store. To get support for multi language localization we recently changed the localization configuration.

Old configuration:

```
./Localizable.strings
```

New Configuration:

```
./Swedish.lproj/General.strings
./Swedish.lproj/Localizable.strings
./Swedish.lproj/Settings.strings
```

If I remove the old version and install the new one everything works as expected, but if I leave the old version on the phone when I install the new one, the translations in `./Swedish.lproj/Localizable.strings` won't be visible. So it seems to me like the old `./Localizable.strings` is still left on the phone, hiding the new `./Swedish.lproj/Localizable.strings`. The translations in `./Swedish.lproj/General.strings` and `./Swedish.lproj/Settings.strings` both works.

My fear is that if we release the update as is the users would be forced to uninstall the app before installing the update to get the translations to work, which would mean that they lose all their saved data. So you can see why this issue has high priority.

If I have understood the cause of the problem correctly, my question is how do I get rid of the `./Localizable.strings` already present on the phone? The more general question would be how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you testing this in debug mode and Xcode is installing the new binary onto the device/simulator or are you doing an Adhoc build-and-archive and then test the update via itunes?

I know that xcode at times will not overwrite files when doing an build and run in debug mode. A touch of the file will not help, but only a clean-all, exit and restart of both Xcode and simulator cures it.

If you are using the adhoc build then the complete app bundle sould be overwritten. If this is not working something serious is at fault.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. It seems that you are correct. We won't know for sure until the app is released, but based on the tests we've done we're expecting it to work.